# Adding cookie consent to an HTML website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have an HTML website that I would like to add Cookie-Consent to it.

Something like Stackoverflow: [Stackoverflow Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DB01.png)

There will be text that may contain links like in the screenshot, But there will be a button saying "I accept" instead of the "x".

I searched about that and found that common library [cookieconsent](https://github.com/insites/cookieconsent) by insites.

Can I create a simple cookie consent to my HTML website or that kind of libraries are better for compatibility and other advantages?

I mean if it's simple, Why would I need to add extra Javascript libraries that would add extra loading time for the website?

Comment: As a reminder, if you use Cloudflare, you can add this kind of "chore" via their "app" section. You don't need to edit your site's code or, try to develop a cookie manager thing. Also they serve it through their CDN and most probably speed up some other things for your site too.

Answer (score 2):

So you definitely don't have to use libraries and it is completely possible to write your own implementation if you wish.

However you have to come up with a mechanism that remembers what users clicked and make it cross-browser compatible. Libraries take care of this for you and are usually already very small. The build folder of the library you linked contains no more than 25kb of code and has the above functionality already built in for you.